# Where does automatically refreshed DE go?

Tags: automationstudio

I've been trying to create an automation in Automation Studio to refresh some Data Extensions based on a simple filter.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320525&type=1&mode=1

At the end it asks me for a name of a resulting Data Extension but where does this extension go? I can see it is created by running a query on the name of the data extension but it's not showing in any folder.

**Edit: Thank you for all your responses. I just found that the target DEs are being generated inside the folder of the master data extension which I was filtering...**

Comment: Usually the created DE will default to the folder of the targeted DE. So if the source DE is in `Data Extensions > myDEs` so too will be your filtered DE. If it is an already existing filtered DE, you can check out this article I wrote on refreshing filtered DEs via REST API (https://gortonington.com/refresh-a-filtered-data-extension-via-rest-api/)

Comment: Thank you, this was it!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it appears in ***Synchronized Data Extensions*** Folder, as you can see below step-by-step:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So after creating a **filter definition** (in data filters folder) you need to create a **filter activity** and append it to an automation. If your resulting Data Extension still not appearing you can follow this guide that zuzanna wrote (extremely helpful) to identify the path of your resulting Data Extension.

https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/14/find-a-data-extension-and-its-folder-path-using-ssjs/

Answer (score 0):

**Moved to an answer for easier visibility:**

Usually the created DE will default to the folder of the targeted DE. So if the source DE is in `Data Extensions > myDEs` so too will be your filtered DE.

If it is an already existing filtered DE, you can check out this article I wrote on [**refreshing filtered DEs via REST API**](http://gortonington.com/refresh-a-filtered-data-extension-via-rest-api)